# NSDictionary with NSArray is converting to array of elements while posting the data to PHP using AfNetworking 2

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, arrays, afnetworking-2

```
NSDictionary *partyOne = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"type",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"status",
                              @"name", @"name",
                              @"name", @"nid",
                              @"name", @"nationality",
                              @"", @"address",
                              @"name", @"mobile",
                              nil];

    NSDictionary *partyTwo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"type",
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"status",
                              @"name", @"name",
                              @"name", @"nid",
                              @"name", @"nationality",
                              @"", @"address",
                              @"name", @"mobile",
                              nil];


    NSArray *partyArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: partyOne, partyTwo, nil];

   NSDictionary  *finalData =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: partyArray forKey:@"details"];
```

When I send the above NSDictionary to AFNetworking 2 at php  as below,

```
// Send the data to server
    NSDictionary *regDic = [self generteJasonData];

    // Send the registered data to server
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:userName password:userpassWd];
     manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager setShouldUseCredentialStorage:NO];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://testlink/submit"parameters:regDic];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    AFJSONResponseSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setResponseSerializer:serializer ];
    [operation setShouldUseCredentialStorage:NO];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
        [manager.requestSerializer clearAuthorizationHeader];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@ responce :%@", error,operation.responseString);
        [manager.requestSerializer clearAuthorizationHeader];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"upload", @"")                                                                                         message:NSLocalizedString(@"Some error occureed while uploading data, please tryagain later", @"")
                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];


    }];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [operation start];
```

i am receiving  it at my php server as ,

```
details =             (
                                {
                    address = "";
                },
                                {
                    mobile = name;
                },
                               {
                    name = name;
                },
                                {
                    nationality = name;
                },
                                {
                    nid = name;
                },
                               {
                    status = 1;
                },
                                {
                    type = 2;
                },
                                {
                    address = "";
                },            {
                    mobile = name;
                },           {
                    name = name;
                },
                                {
                    nationality = name;
                },
                                {
                    nid = name;
                },
                       {
                    status = 1;
                },
                                {
                    type = 2;
                },
            );
```

i.e. I have sending 2 array elements, but i am receiving it as many array elements.
Can anyone let me know what was the problem here. is their any issue with AFNetworking 2.0 APIs or problem with my code.

Comment: Here `NSDictionary  *finalData =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arrayDictionary forKey:@"details"];`  what is `arrayDictionary` ?

Comment: @katre, I have edited my query. it is "partyArray"

Comment: I bumped into the same problem , Vaz, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Ok , so what you need to do , is to fix the method

```
NSArray * AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue(NSString *key, id value)
```

in the file AFURLRequestSerialization.m : 
instead of

```
for (id nestedValue in array)
```

make it

```
for (int i = 0;i < [array count];++i)
```

and then instead of

```
[mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[]", key], nestedValue)];
```

make it

```
[mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%d]", key,i], nestedValue)];
```

Comment: superb answer bro. I am shocked why this answer is not accepted but you should explain it more

Comment: Dude, you just saved my day :), i just spent my half day for this issue. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking 2.0 : I used @gilad answer and modified it a bit to make it work properly. So what i did is written below :

```
NSArray * AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue(NSString *key, id value) {
   NSMutableArray *mutableQueryStringComponents = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];

  if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = value;
    // Sort dictionary keys to ensure consistent ordering in query string, which is important when deserializing potentially ambiguous sequences, such as an array of dictionaries
    for (id nestedKey in [dictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ sortDescriptor ]]) {
        id nestedValue = [dictionary objectForKey:nestedKey];
        if (nestedValue) {
            [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue((key ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%@]", key, nestedKey] : nestedKey), nestedValue)];
        }
    }
  } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

   // This is modified by me
    NSArray *array = value;
    int i = 0;
    for (id nestedValue in array) {
    // A check has been added for NSDictionary
        if ([nestedValue isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
           //Here i used @gilad's answer 
            [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[%d]", key,i], nestedValue)];

        }else{

        [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[]", key], nestedValue)];
        }
        i++;
    }
   } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]]) {
       NSSet *set = value;
       for (id obj in [set sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ sortDescriptor ]]) {
            [mutableQueryStringComponents addObjectsFromArray:AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue(key, obj)];
       }
   } else {
       [mutableQueryStringComponents addObject:[[AFQueryStringPair alloc] initWithField:key value:value]];
   }

    return mutableQueryStringComponents;
}
```

I just edited the AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue in AFURLRequestSerialization.m class as mentioned above and then it start working the way we wanted.

Comment: How can use this? I need to do request with following format, 
[
    {
        "path": "/",
        "value": {
            "state": "ACTIVE"
        },
        "op": "replace"
    }
]

Can you explain more? show me your usage code..

Comment: @karthikeyan my request was like [{}, {},{}] format. As i have mentioned in my answer i have replaced NSArray * AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue(NSString *key, id value) this method with mines

Comment: @karthikeyan if you are still looking for the solution then you can tell me. i can try giving you edited AFNetworking framework

Comment: thanks for replay, I have done this By using NSMutableString, i just made formate like that, and converted into data, then sent it to server, that will work for me,